# What is sonar Delphi Plugin ? How to use it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using Delphi 7. I am trying to use Sonar Delphi Plgin, and I have confused what are the things I need to follow, **could anybody guide me through Sonar Delphi usage i.e. installation and how to use it.**

If possible pl provide the link, coz I have gone through the link below, but it gives me only jar file:

```
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin
```

And confused with one more link:

```
http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-VOTE-Delphi-plugin-td4523726.html
```

Here is the following link for Sonar runner:

```
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner
```

Comment: It tries to ensure software quality for you.  **CPD (code duplication, how many lines, block and in how many files), “Dead” code recognition, Unused files recognition** is what I might be interested in. Thank you for the question. I'll share my experience with you, when I install it and use it on my project.

Comment: I don't understand you. When I go to http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin I see lots of documentation and an example project. Did you try that?

Comment: There I have already gone through, I didn't get what has to be done with downloaded .jar file and how to make a setup. In update center, there I didn't find anythinfor installtion.

Comment: Have a look at: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/miguelangeloliver/2012/11/22/installing-sonar-for-delphi/ its a nice step by step guide.

Comment: It's all there on the SONAR site. Did you install SONAR yet? Did you read the instructions on how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Based off of recent memory of getting this working.

- Ensure Java 6 SDK installed  (Delphi addon doesn't work with Java 7)
- Download the Sonar application: http://www.sonarsource.org/downloads/
- Install Sonar
- Run Sonar  (StartSonar.bat)
- Once logged on (default user/pass is admin) install the Delphi add-on via the Update Center list of Available Plugins.  See: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center
- Grab the example project files from the Github repository: 
  https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages
  There's a Delphi sample in there demonstrating how to configure a sonar-project.properties file that points to your source code directories.
- After setting the SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable, exec 'sonar-runner' in the folder with your configured properties file to have Sonar parse through the Delphi project files.

I plan to go back to play with this, but it failed to process most of the code I threw at it so I walked away a bit disappointed.  It seems like a pretty cool system.

Comment: "it failed to process
most of the code I threw at it" sounds pretty much like a show stopper

Comment: Looking at Sonar again - few steps to install online https://github.com/darianmiller/devmachine/wiki/Install-Sonar

Comment: So far so good this time around - Sonar exclusions prevent duplicate source found in __History files causing havoc.